# Задать переменную из второй строки

Tags: cmd

Есть скрипт:

```
for /f %%a in ('WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name^=%product% get Version') do set var1=%%a
```

Который выдает 3 строки:

```
set var1=Version

set var1=16.4.0.0

set var1=
```

В результате в переменной остается только последняя, то есть ничего.
Как вывести в переменную 2 строку - 16.4.0.0 ?

Comment: Команда **for** может парсить текст с использованием  разделителя - параметр **delims**. В качестве разделителя можно использовать символ =, который получится, если утилите **wmic** последним параметром добавить параметр **/value**. Таким образом нужно добавить обработку разделителя: **for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('wmic... get Version /value') do set var1=%%b**

Answer (score 0):

Так тоже не работает, version /value выдает результат, а потом еще 2 пустых строки, которые и попадают в переменную, но это я обошел с помощью IF

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in ('WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name
^=%product% get Version /value') do if %%a==Version set var=%%b

Однако хотелось бы все же понять, есть ли возможность построчно выбирать результат через FOR.

Comment: Конечно же есть, если известно каким номером следует строка с необходимыми значениями. Для этого у парсера **for** имеется опция **skip** пропускающая нужное количество строк. Пример того, как пропустить две строки:  **for /f "delims== tokens=1,2 skip=2"**

Comment: skip пропускает верхние строки, но если после нужной идут пустые, то они и попадут в отбор

Comment: для этого есть утилиты фильтрации вывода - например, утилиты **find** или **findstr**. добавьте в конце команды, которую обрабатывает парсер, и в выводе пропадут пустые строки. Однако нужно учитывать, что при использовании утилиты wmic в вывод консоли попадают с виду пустые строки, но содержащие пробелы или иные не отображаемые символы. Фильтровать их сложнее. Именно **по этой причине** я предложил обрабатывать значения 1-го и 2-го параметра в **единой строке**